# Sound will not play in JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a problem and I hope you can help me. 
Some talk about what I am doing so you know what's going on: So at the moment I'm trying to program a litte piece of software which can play me some music files (mp3 files to be exact, so i'm using the jLayer API). I'm working with Netbeans and I have succesfully imported a music file in the project. If I build my program and open the resulting JAR file with an archive program, I can find my music file in there. My function which I'm using goes like this:

```
    public static String play(String file)  {
    File test = new File(file);
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(test);
        Player pl = new Player(in);
        pl.play();
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm getting a String with the Path Name and refactor him so I can play the file. I'm calling the function with the following code (the music file is saved in the ressources package):

```
MP3.play(getClass().getResource("/ressources/angel.mp3").getPath())
```

So if I start the programm via Netbeans everything works perfectly fine. But if I create a JAR file and start the program nothing happens. The Exception getting is the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MP3\dist\MP3.jar!\ressources\angel.mp3
```

It says the File does not exist but if I check my JAR the file is there......

Another strange thing I found out is the following: If I use the following function to play the music file:

```
    public static String play(InputStream test)  {
    try {
        Player pl = new Player(test);
        pl.play();
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }

}
```

and call the function with the following argument:

```
MP3.play(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ressources/angel.mp3"));
```

Everything works fine in both Netbeans and the final JAR. Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong and only the second function works in the JAR version?

It would be really nice if you could help me in this matter.

Greetings,
xXKnightRiderXx

Comment: I see a `MP3.jar!` in the FileNotFoundException. Is the actual name of the file?

Comment: Resources are not files and don't work with FileInputStream or most File related APIs. Either extract the resource from the jar and then use FileInputStream on the separate file or just always use getResourceAsStream() directly.

Comment: @ILikeTau yeah you are right there is an "!" in the file name and that is not the actual name of the file. But I already tried removing the "!" before I use the string further, but that did not solve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have 2 packages 1 is src where your .java files is located and other is resources where your sound files is located

So i suggest you to use

```
MP3.play(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/angel.mp3"));
```

Because GetResource() automatically finds the resource package